Break the lightning-tab label to two lines
I am using Lightning tab-set in which I have 5 tabs. I want to show the tab label in 2 lines.
Example :
Step 1 -
Choose Ingredients

Here is my snippet :
<lightning-tab label="Step 1 - Choose Ingredients" value="Ingredients" onactive={handleActive}>

label accepts a string so I am unable to use a breakpoint tag in between. How can I achieve the output in two lines?

This isn't going to be possible with the base lighting-tab component without  some really hacky solutions. Your best bet will be to build a custom tab component using SLDS.
Tabset is also one of the LWCs available in the base-component-recipe github repository! So you can start from there.
